# Adding an outer name to JSON response in API

Tags: c#, json

I have written an API which returns data in JSON format.

The response looks like:

```
[{"leadID":1,"eventID":2,"companyID":3},{"leadID":4,"eventID":5,"companyID":6}]
```

But to me that does not ideal, I would like to add a name to this collection.

Ideally I would like the output to be like:

```
{"data":[{"leadID":1,"eventID":2,"companyID":3},{"leadID":4,"eventID":5,"companyID":6}]}
```

My action is:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetLeadsSinceLastPoll()
{
    using (var context = new MyDbContext())
    {
        var leads = context.Lead.Where(q => q.dateAdded > AuthorizedUser.LastPollDate).ToList();
        var x = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(leads);
        var res = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        res.Content = new StringContent(x, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        return res;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to add an outer name/label to the result?

Answer (score 1):

If you want `leads` to be the `data` property of an object, that's easy: Just create an object like that, and serialize it. With serialization, it's always best to manipulate the objects, not the serialized text. One unescaped quotation mark can wreak havoc. You don't want to get tangled up in those details.

```
var obj = new { data = leads };
var x = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```

Or if you're using an old version of C# (< C#4) that doesn't support anonymous types:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<String, Object>();

dict["data"] = leads;

x = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict);
```

Or if you want something so quick and dirty that it actually takes longer:

```
var x = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(leads);

x = $@"{{""data"":{x}}}";
```

Answer (score 0):

Create two classes 
Class 1 is a list of Class 2 objects

```
public class Objects
{
    public List<Object1> data;
}

public class Object1
{
    public int LeadID;
    public int EventID;
    public int CompanyID;
}
```

Add items to the list like so:

```
Objects ObjectList = new Objects()
{
    data= new List<Object1>()
};

Object1 object= new Object1()
{
    LeadID = 1,
    EventID = 2,
    CompanyID = 3
};

ObjectList.data.Add(object);
```

Convert ObjectList to Json:

```
string jsonTxt = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ObjectList);
```